# Creating Custom Keyboard like emoji

Tags: iphone, ios5

Is it possible to create custom Keyboard in iPhone which can get use by any other application. Similar to the Emoji keyboard. Is it possible to take advantage of the international keyboard feature for the iPhone and create a custom keyboard that can be used over for apps on iPhone?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find out .. how to add this custom Emoji keyboard as international keyboard for the device ? 
Can the keyboard be used globally in the device ?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is exploit the inputView property of textField. You can create a UIView having buttons on it like the keys in key board, and set action for each buttons. Do actions appropriately for tapping each key.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this solution will work only for my application. So whatever keyboard I am going to create will be applicable in my app not in others. How can I add this keyboard in Settings->General->Keyboard->International Keyboard and then in keyboard list??